# How does LED Flashes One by One in my Project Some Queries?

Tags: led, flash

I have a project called LED Flasher which Flashes LED’s one by one….but I have following Query about my project…..if anyone can explain me it in simple words it will be great help for me…..one can use Below image for reference…or use this [link](http://www.gregsbasicelectronics.com/circuits/ledoscillator.htm)

1. How does capacitor C1 and C2 being charged through resistor R3,R4 and Diode D3, D4?
2. Couldn’t understand how LED D1 and D2 Flashes one by one…what is the actual Current flow in this Circuit? Could anyone explain it in Simple Word?

Thanks……a lot....
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overwhelming problems here are that the circuit diagram is wrong and cannot work
 AND the circuit he has built **DOES** actually match the diagram!

Nowhere in the video (I skimmed it) does it show the flasher flashing - which would seem somewhat strange.

While this claim seems "rather hard to believe" [tm] a look at the many many many 2-transistor astable multivibrator circuits from the link below will show that they all work the same way AND that none match his circuit.

The problem with his circuit is that R3 & R4 should go from the base of each transistor to B+ (battery+) and NOT from base to ground.

[Here are many many many circuits that agree with each other and which his fails to match -](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=astable+multivibrator&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvnsb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=lWFgT6XVLcKZiAf2u_yeAg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CA8Q_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=1081#q=transistor+astable+multivibrator&hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=73bf21ade80a3c8&biw=1920&bih=1081)

[image]

Here is the rear view of his DED Flasher which shows that it is indeed built as he shows in the circuit diagram:

This circuit diagram [from here](http://www.play-hookey.com/digital/experiments/rtl_astable.html)

[image]

Or this one [from here](http://www.google.co.nz/imgres?imgurl=http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/tim20.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html&h=258&w=471&sz=10&tbnid=ISBEBhVFQiozSM:&tbnh=66&tbnw=120&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dastable%2Bmultivibrator%26tbm%3Disch%26tbo%3Du&zoom=1&q=astable+multivibrator&docid=RYuku8vWmO6zCM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lWFgT6XVLcKZiAf2u_yeAg&ved=0CDsQ9QEwAw&dur=96)

[image]

Or all the following and more [from here](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=astable+multivibrator&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvnsb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=lWFgT6XVLcKZiAf2u_yeAg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CA8Q_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=1081#q=transistor+astable+multivibrator&hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=73bf21ade80a3c8&biw=1920&bih=1081) (as above) show he is wrong.

**Many of those pages will describe correct operation** BUT before you read them, with the new circuit, see if you can see how it works, then look it up. The correct answer will almost certainly surprise you.

[image]

---

**OPERATION:**

Assume no cap leakage.

All off.
 C1! discharged,. C2 discharged.
 Power on.
 C1+, C2+ pulled high via LEDs by battery.
 As C1 and C2 have no V across them the -ve sides will also be pulled high.
 Bothe bases pulled high - boty transistors try to turn on.
 One will win.
 Say Q1 turning on faster:
 C2 will have some charge as -ve side discharged via base (or left side chgd via R1 D1).
 QA Q1-c is driven to ground, C2- will be driven to BELOW ground.
 Q2 driven hard off
 If C2- driven more than about 0.6V below ground D4 conducts to clamp -ve excursion.  Also provides a discharge path via Q1 - see below.
. 
 Now Q1 on Q2 off.
 C1+ will charge via R2D2 (not a robot).
 Usually R4 is to B+ and it charges C2 so Q2 turns on. 
 Q1 is on as above as C1 high but C1 is charging via R2 D2 C1 R3 so -ve end falls until Q1 is not held on as Vb too low.
 But now C2 is discharged due to path Ground-D4-C2-Q1. So when Q1 turns off Collector of C1 rises and lifts C2+ and so C2- follows so Q2 turns on and identical second half cycle happens

This is a much damaged version of the original as usually bases are driven negative and do not conduct during timing part of cycle and resistor charges capacitor via a normal time constant. Here the caps forward bias the bases when the opposite collector rises and you get massive base current pulse via eg R1 D1 C2 Q2_base. So time constant of RC is much shortened so oscillator will run rather faster than usually. T = RC of bases is notionally 10k x 100 uf = 1 second but because capacitors are clamped and discharged directly into bases this will run much faster.

So it works after a fashion but is crippled.

Comment: hi thank you so much for giving me answer...BTW,...do u mean that above circuit shows in image which i have uploaded is wrong?........but i have make circuit using that diagram and its working nicely.....two LED flashes One By One....but the problem is i Can't understand ....exact flow of Current in circuit? how capacitor Charge-discharge and transistor On-Off? couldn't understand?........thank you so much for giving answer......

Comment: I don't think the original circuit is a great idea, but I disagree that it can't work.  The biggest issue is that it will have a startup problem.  However, consider how it works if one transistor was on and the other off.  Eventually the capacitor keeping the on transistor on will charge up and base current will cease.  This will turn the transistor off, which raises it's collector, which drives the other transistor on.  I do think the topology is a kludge, as evidenced by the need for the diodes to ensure the caps are discharged during the appropriate part of the cycle.

Comment: I've been having much discussion re this elsewhere. The issue is that he uses the startup surge to start the circuit OR the capacitor leakage. If caps have more than about 50 uA leakage it will strat from rest. Some caps will work some wont. If you apply DC to the circuit both caps pull the connected bases high and one transistor then wins as usual. The usual circuit does not rely in a startup power supply transient to oscillate.

Answer (score 2):

> How does capacitor C1 and C2 being charged through resistor R3,R4 and Diode D3, D4?

They are not charged through D3 and D4. They are charged through the LEDs D1 and D2.

> Couldn’t understand how LED D1 and D2 Flashes one by one…what is the actual Current flow in this Circuit? Could anyone explain it in Simple Word?

My take on the original designer`s explanation of this circuit:

Assume that C2 is charged to an arbitrary voltage >0 and C1 is discharged. Also assume that Q1 is on first. (The circuit relies on inherent tolerance value differences to determine which transistor fires first, so the first cycle is hard to predict.)

Q1 is turned on through the R2 - D2 - C1 - R3 path. Q1 illuminates the LED and discharges C2 to a low level by (essentially) connecting the positive to ground. D4 allows for faster discharge by shunting R4.

Over time C1 charges up and builds up a voltage which opposes the 9V supply. At a certain point, once C1 charges to a sufficient level, Q1 will turn off.

C2 is essentially discharged so once Q1 turns off, Q2 turns on through the R1 - D2 - C2 - R4 path. Q2 discharges C1 too (with D3 shunting R3 for fast discharge). Now C2 charges, and eventually Q2 will turn off and Q1 will turn on.

If you build it and take some measurements with a scope or a multimeter, you can validate my (and Russell's) statements (that is to say: let`s see if it actually works!)